# Using joint density to calculate probability that one person dies before the other

Tags: probability

Let $T_x, T_y$ be two random variables that describe the remaining lifetime of two persons aged $x$ and $y$, respectively. The joint density of $T_x$ and $T_y$ is given by

$$f_{T_x,T_y}(s,t)=\begin{cases}\frac{2}{45}\cdot20^{-4}\cdot\Big(9 \cdot 20^2-(3s-t)^2\Big)&,s \in [0,20], t\in[0,60]\\0&, \mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

How can I use this to determine the probability that the person aged $y$ dies before the person aged $x$?

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate the joint density over the region where $T_y$ is less than $T_x$. I suggest drawing a picture. Your integration region is the rectangle $(s,t) \in [0,20]\times[0,60]$ where $s$ corresponds to $T_x$ and $t$ corresponds to $T_y$. If you draw the line $s = t$ you should be able to work out the limits of integration from there.

Comment: So what are my limits of integration?

Comment: I added some additional hints above. Short answer: draw a picture and it should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a rectangle boundary for the joint PDF, where x axis in $[0,20]$ and y axis is $[0,60]$. We need $P(T_y<T_x)$. $y$ is smaller than $x$ below $y=x$ line. So, you need to integrate the joint in the region bounded by the lines $y=x,\ \ y=0, \ \ x=20$ as follows:

$$P(T_y<T_x)=\int_{0}^{20}\int_{0}^{x}f(x,y)dydx$$